# Как использовать utcoffset временной зоны для конвертации времени?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, временная-зона

Время на сервере установлено в UTC. У меня есть список объектов, для которых указан часовой пояс в таком формате: `+0300`. Есть ли встроенные средства, которые позволят конвертировать время в локальное из UTC, не изобретая велосипед?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Что вы называете "локальным временем" если это не время сервера? Т.е. как программа знает, какая временная зона является локальной?

Comment: @RomanKonoval  список объектов для которых в бд указана таймзона в том виде, в котором я написал. +0300 - это часовой пояс Москвы, например. Для этого объекта московское время и будет локальным.

Comment: У вас много __различных__ (уникальных) значений сдвига времени (таких как `+0300`)?

Comment: Все еще не понятно. Вот есть у вас объект с часовым поясом `+0300`. Можно конвертировать его **в** UTC. А вы же спрашиваете о конвертации из UTC. Когда вы конвертируете из UTC, то это происходит явно не для того объекта из БД где уже есть зона `+0300`, а для объекта с зоной UTC. Вот и вопрос, откуда известна "локальная" зона при такой конвертации? Это какой-то глобальный параметр, который не является временой зоной сервера?

Comment: Не сводится ли ваш вопрос к "есть объект с таймзоной, нужно конвертировать его в другую зону"?

Comment: @RomanKonoval по сути да, именно к этому и сводится мой вопрос. Но основная суть именно в формате. Модуль `dateutil.tz` имеет метод `gettz`, но он принимает название зоны, формат, который я пишу - это просто строка в БД. Вопрос прежде всего о том, как получить из этой строки объект временной зоны в питоне. Я не могу этого нигде найти. Либо я не понимаю как это искать.

Comment: @MaxU не совсем понятно, что такое много. Но да, их несколько.

Comment: __стандартные__ средства работы с временными зонами предполагают работу с каноническими именами временны зон, такими как `'Europe/Moscow'`. Поэтому если у вас таких значений не много их можно замапить в канонические названия временных зон и дальше уже пользоваться стандартными либами

Comment: Вы можете сформулировать вопрос в виде "нужно написать функцию с параметрами таких-то типов (и примеры можно включить) и получить на выходе то-то". Мне все еще не ясно, что у вас на входе, с учетом оговорок про формат таймзоны.

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, это именно то, что я хотел услышать. То есть стандартных средств работы с таким форматом нет, а не у меня проблемы с гуглением. Коли так, я что-нибудь придумаю.

Comment: @RomanKonoval моя задача предельно простая. Допустим сейчас по UTC ровно 12:00:00. Какое сейчас время в таймозне `+0300`?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, а вообще если бы вы привели реальный пример данных, то все было бы проще ;) Как у вас хранится дата/время - как UNIX timestamp, т.е. целое число? ЗЫ у меня появилась идея, но надо понимать как у вас хранятся даты

Comment: @MaxU а нет хранения дат, хранится только вот это значение таймзоны. Дату мне надо получить текущую просто как `datetime.now()` и перевести ее в локальное время конкретного объекта.

Comment: @MaxU может быть мне проще вообще в базе снести эти значения и поменять на названия зон. Я не знаю кто когда и зачем такой формат выбрал :)  Что если есть зимнее время, например, что тогда будут значить эти +0300? Наверное нет смысла это хранить

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, Roman Konoval написал  [идиоматический ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1314020/211923) (+1) - воспользуйтесь им)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конвертирование времени с временной зоной в другую заданую сторокой формата `+0300` стандартными средствами делается так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt_to_convert = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

tz = datetime.strptime('+0300', '%z').tzinfo

dt_in_03_tz = dt_to_convert.astimezone(tz)
```

Answer (score 3):

https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-datetime-python/klass-timezone-modulja-datetime/

```
import datetime

tz = datetime.timezone(offset, name=None)
```

параметры:

```
offset - объект datetime.timedelta(), смещение от UTC,
name=None - строка, название часового пояса.
```

Думаю Вам поможет данная статья о классе timezone() модуля datetime в Python.
Также можете спарсить строку в datetime с часовым поясом, как в этой статье https://codecamp.ru/blog/python-date-and-time/

Для python 3.2+

```
import datetimedt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-04-15T08:27:18-0500", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Для других версий Python можно использовать внешнюю библиотеку, такую ​​как dateutil, которая проанализирует текст в объект datetime.

```
import dateutil.parserdt = dateutil.parser.parse("2016-04-15T08:27:18-0500")
```

Теперь переменная dt представляет собой объект datetime со следующим значением:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 15, 8, 27, 18, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

В целом можете ознакомиться с модулем datetime: https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html
Успехов)

Comment: Ответ только со ссылкой - плохой. Ссылка может устареть. Включите в ответ важную часть, чтоб он был самодостаточным.

Comment: Вопрос прежде всего в том, является ли такой формат `+0300` дефолтным для какого-то метода получения таймозоны. В статье никакого подобного примера я не вижу, там речь про таймдельту. Да, я могу распарсить эти `+0300`, получить из них часы и минуты и прибавить их к UTC времени. Но точно ли это хороший путь, или есть что-то встроенное, понимающее что такое +0300?